# dev_appserver.py with runtime go111 url dispatch problem

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am still working to get my old style appengines to work under at least go111 (go112 would not work due to dependencies on memcache). I am now stumbling over app.yaml configuration issues with my static files, I used a completely static directory layout before and just specified a few dynamic handlers in the root like this:

```
runtime: go111

handlers:
- url: /_ah/.*
 script: auto
 login: admin
 secure: always
- url: /dynamic
 script: auto
 secure: always
- url: /admin/.*
 script: auto
 login: admin
 secure: always
- url: (.*)/
 static_files: html\1/index.html
 upload: html/index.html
 secure: always
- url: /(.*\.map)
 mime_type: application/json
 static_files: html/\1
 upload: html/(.*\.map)
 secure: always
- url: /
 static_dir: html
 secure: always
```

dev_appserver.py will never call my dynamic entry point. In production this does work, but I am still working on the conversion and would like to test locally. Any hints how to convince dev_appserver.py to let me do this? By the way my gcloud tools are updated as of today.

Comment: Could you clarify a few things to me? because I'm not sure which is the issue that you are facing. I'm assuming you are working with App Engine standard since is not specified on the app.yaml and you are using "dev_appserver.py" (which only works on standard), correct?.  You have used configured your handlers to handle static files and with an entrypoint (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/config/appref#handlers_script),  right?.

Comment: And it works when deployed but it doesn't handle the urls when using the local server dev_appserver.py https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server, correct?.

Comment: Yes, I am working with standard, that is what I am getting if not specifying anything else. I have dependencies on memcache which I am not yet able to resolve otherwise, so I am stuck with go111 runtime. Previously I have been using the go runtime with api version go1. And it does work perfectly deployed with the gcloud command, but debugging locally with dev_appserver.py does not work, it will only serve static content and no handlers are called.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is why your application works well when you deploy it to production but doesn't work when you use **dev_appserver.py** to run it locally, and how could you run it with **dev_appserver.py**. The answer to that is:

You won't be able to run it locally properly using **dev_appserver.py**, since it does not support runtime Go 1.11. Look at the [Local Development Server Options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/local-devserver-command) documentation, there's only a link for "Go 1.9".

[image]

*(as you can see, the links for "Go 1.11" and "Go 1.12" are disabled, which translates to: not supported.)*

[Documentation for Go 1.11](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/testing-and-deploying-your-app) on App Engine Standard states that in order to test your application locally you would have to use "go run" command (notice how it doesn't mention dev_appserver.py tool). The command would be something like this:

```
go run [build flags] [-exec xprog] package [arguments...]
```

For more information about the command go [here](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program).

I'm sure you might have already read this but, to know more about the migrations process from Go1.9 to Go1.11 read this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences).

You have stated that "go run" command wouldn't work for your case. So, a workaround for that would be to [test your application directly into App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/testing-and-deploying-your-app) but **without migrating the traffic**.

When deploying your test version use:

```
gcloud app deploy --no-promote
```

To access to it go to:

```
http://VERSION_ID.default.YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com
```

If everything turned out great, you can migrate the traffic on the [Cloud Console UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions?_ga=2.39258597.-730435798.1562054471&_gac=1.251391666.1562054529.EAIaIQobChMI76nYrOKV4wIVyRnTCh0yMw7YEAAYASAAEgJGvPD_BwE) selecting the version you just deployed and clicking "**Migrate traffic**".

Comment: If I look at the dev_appserver.py docs, it only has a "go" link, there is nothing about versions. And for standard app engine apps, a simple "go run" will not do, as you have none of the local api emulation stuff that dev_appserver.py starts and that is required for any of the standard appengine imports to work, for example you have no local memcache emulation. Memcache is one of the features I cannot remove from my appengine apps, and the 1.12 referral to the redis cloud would be just way to exensive for my small apps.

Comment: The one running as "develop" version fits my other workflow pretty well, so I can use that for the time being. But not being able to do local testing while offline (e.g. while traveling) is a bummer. I believe I will have to reconsider my decision to go with appengine, as me being a digital nomad having good internet access is an exception, not the norm.

Comment: Glad to know that the workaround will be able to fit on your workflow